# Haskell-platform throws a ton of errors when I try to install it on WSL

Tags: haskell, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install haskell-platform on my Windows 10 linux subsystem, but just installing it throws a ton of errors. I tried this, according to the haskell site:

```
$ sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

And it threw more than my terminal saved, and this at the end.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ghc
 libghc-text-dev
 libghc-attoparsec-dev
 libghc-hunit-dev
 ghc-haddock
 libghc-stm-dev
 libghc-async-dev
 libghc-hashable-dev
 libghc-case-insensitive-dev
 libghc-extensible-exceptions-dev
 libghc-transformers-dev
 libghc-mtl-dev
 libghc-monadcatchio-mtl-dev
 libghc-parsec3-dev
 libghc-network-dev
 libghc-xhtml-dev
 libghc-cgi-dev
 libghc-fgl-dev
 libghc-openglraw-dev
 libghc-gluraw-dev
 libghc-opengl-dev
 libghc-glut-dev
 libghc-syb-dev
 libghc-haskell-src-dev
 libghc-html-dev
 libghc-http-dev
 libghc-parallel-dev
 libghc-primitive-dev
 libghc-random-dev
 libghc-quickcheck2-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to apt-get remove, but it threw errors and didn't complete that, either. Is there a safe way to start over and try again? Has anyone else encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: The end is useless. We already know everything has filed, no surprise here. The **first** error message may be helpful.

Comment: Are you on a windows insider build? There were issues with WSL that prevented installing Haskell before, but I think they were fixed on the most recent insiders build (and should be coming to everyone else in the next major Windows 10 update).

Comment: @jkeuhlen, That is good to know. I'm not on an insider build. Is it worth doing as a developer? I was worried it might result in lower stability or less support.

Comment: @n.m. Good point! Here's a pastebin of the full output. It's shorter and different this time, though because it's already partially installed and probably corrupted somehow... http://pastebin.com/XgWx6u7H

Comment: Googling this first error message `ghc: timer_create: Function not implemented` returns a number of hits.

Comment: @IanEdwards Yes. You have to be on an insider build (the most recent one, near build# 15000 I believe) for any of Haskell to work. It does come with lower stability. Personally, I'm just waiting for the creators update to play with Haskell on the WSL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `timer_create` is not implemented on your current build of the Windows Linux subsystem, aka **WSL**. If you have a recent OS, you can uninstall your current WSL and reinstall it. This will only work if your Windows version is 64-bit and build 1607 or later. You can find the build number from **Start menu Settings**, then select **System -> About**

[image]

Use the following commands from a command shell (not bash shell) to uninstall and reinstall. IMPORTANT: Back up your Linux files before running these commands as this deletes all of them.

```
lxrun /uninstall /full /y
lxrun /install /y
```

Once the install is complete you can open a Windows command prompt and update WSL with:

```
lxrun /update
```

Once you've re-installed and updated, you can `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` from the within bash shell.

This worked on one of my computers, but not the other. Not sure why. If it does not work, you can get the latest WSL distro by joining the *Insiders Build*; instructions [here](https://insider.windows.com/GetInsiderBuilds).

**Useful Links**

- Windows help on [lxrun](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/reference).
- Instructions on [WSL installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide).